# Ctools Form Wizard Dynamic Fields Rebuilding

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, forms

I just started rebuilding our subscription form as a Ctools Wizard Form which is great for storing values, and easy to use. Here is the code for building the form and saving the objects in ctools cache:

```
function subscription_poll($js = NULL, $step = NULL) {

  $form_info = array(
    'id' => 'subscription-form', //form id
    // 'path' => "poll/" . ($js ? 'ajax' : 'nojs') . "/%step", //pass the step we're on to the form, step1, step2, ..etc
    'path' => "poll/%step", //pass the step we're on to the form, step1, step2, ..etc
    'show trail' => TRUE, //show the breadcrumb / path trail for the forms
    'show back' => TRUE, //show the back button
    'show cancel' => TRUE, //show the cancel button
    'show return' => FALSE, //show the update and return button
    'next callback' =>  'd7_poll_wizard_next', //a callback function to run when the next button is called
    'finish callback' => 'd7_poll_wizard_finish', //callback when finish button is called
    'cancel callback' => 'd7_poll_wizard_cancel', //callback when cancel button is called
    'order' => array( // this controls order, as well as form labels
      'step1' => t('Step 1'),
      'step2' => t('Step 2'),
    ),
    'forms' => array( // here we map a step to a form id.
      'step1' => array( //what we're doing here is telling the wizard when step1 is passed as arg, show the form with form_id d7_poll_step_1
        'form id' => 'sub_order_form_page_one'
      ),
      'step2' => array(
        'form id' => 'sub_order_form_page_two'
      ),
    ),
  );
  /***********************************************
   * Object caching
   ***********************************************/
   $object_id = 'd7_poll';
   if (empty($step)) {
      d7_cache_clear($object_id);
   }

  $object = d7_cache_get($object_id);
  $form_state = array(
    'ajax' => $js,
    'object_id' => $object_id,
    'object' => &$object,
  );

  // Send this all off to our form. This is like drupal_get_form only wizardy.
  ctools_include('wizard');
  $form = ctools_wizard_multistep_form($form_info, $step, $form_state);

  $output = drupal_render($form);

  return $output;
}
```

Our Form is built as such:

1. The first step of our form is very straight forward, requiring that the user select if the subscription is a gift and if so, how many would they like to purchase. This gives the second step of our form the values necessary to build the number of fieldsets for entering shipping information.
2. The second step is build either with or without the gift subscription fields based on the values entered on the first step of the form. If there are entered values than the form populates x number of fieldsets.
3. We have also included a button which allows the user(s) to be able to add an additional fieldset on that same second form step. This callback:

   ```
   if (!empty($form_state['object']['Gift_Quantity'])){

   $form['add_additional_shipping_fieldset'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit', 
   '#value' => t('Add another gift recipent'), 
   '#submit' => array('add_shipping_address_fieldset'),
   '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),

   ); 
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['object']['Gift_Quantity']; $i++){

   $form['Shipping'][$i] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset', 
    '#title' => t('Gift Subscription #@num', array('@num' => $i)), 
    '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
   );

   $form['Shipping'][$i]['ShippingCountryCode'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Select your Country'),
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#options' => $countries,
        '#required' => TRUE,    
   );
   }
   ```

The trouble that I am having is trying to rebuild the form_state when additional fieldsets are requested through the callback. The formstate is rebuilt via the callback:

```
  function add_shipping_address_fieldset($form, &$form_state) {

  $form_state['object']['Gift_Quantity']++;

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;

 }
```

However the page is redirected to the first step. Any thoughts?